# Php ftp_get(/Outbox/CCDATA.TXT) I can connect to the server but I am not sure how to get in the correct directory

Tags: php, get, ftp

I would like to download a file from an ftp site. I can connect to the site using this.

I get this error:
Warning: ftp_get(/Outbox/CCDATA.TXT): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/dashboard/data/cit_file_download.php on line 16

Warning: ftp_get(): Error opening /Outbox/CCDATA.TXT in /var/www/html/dashboard/data/cit_file_download.php on line 16
Error downloading CCDATA.TXT.

```
conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Couldn't connect to 
$ftp_server"); 

// try to login
if (@ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass)) {
echo "Connected as $ftp_username@$ftp_server\n";
} else {
echo "Couldn't connect as $ftp_username\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

so I know my credentials work. My trouble seems to be in adding a path. the file I need is in a folder called "Outbox" and I have not been successful with anything I have tried.

This is my current code. Thanks for the help

```
$local_file = "order.txt";
$server_file = 'CCDATA.TXT';
$ftp_username="removed";
$ftp_userpass="removed";
$ftp_path = '/Outbox/';
$ftp_server = "removed.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to 
$ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);



// download server file
if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $ftp_path.$server_file, $local_file,  
FTP_ASCII))
 {
 echo "Successfully written to $local_file.";
 }
else
 {
echo "Error downloading $server_file.";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Failed to open stream : No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/php-failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Not a duplicate

Comment: Show us a log file of any standalone FTP client (e.g. WinSCP) proving that you can download `/Outbox/CCDATA.TXT` using the same credentials + Do you have an access to server-side log?

Comment: I have no access to the server logs

Comment: I can connect with filezilla  to that directory and get the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local file should come first then the server file and path.

if (ftp_get($ftp_conn, $local_file, $ftp_path.$server_file,FTP_ASCII))